# Detecting which item is showing in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listener

I have a Recycler View that shows one item at a time. I need to know what index that item is in relation to the Recycler View's other items.

I don't see any listener that i can add to the Recycler View to detect this.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use onScrollListener

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            //For finding first visible item position
            linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            //For finding last visible item position
            linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() s();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Works very well.